# How to generate colors with maximum mutual perceived difference?

Tags: algorithm, colors, vision

I need to generate 9 different colors for use in my application, for color coding purposes. I want the colors to be as mutually distinct from each other as possible, so people can most easily distinguish between any pair of them.

After some research into the problem, I was able to do this by choosing 9 colors equally spaced colors (in HSL space) by choosing each hue 40 degrees apart:

[image]

I've chosen them a bit dark, because they need contrast against the white background of my app.

But even though these colors are mathematically equidistant, they don't appear that way to my eyes. In particular, the 3 greenish tints (3-5 in my image) seem closer to each other than 3 others elsewhere.

I know that this is because the eye doesn't perceive things linearly, so is there an algorithm for choosing equidistant colors **with respect to the way the eye actually sees**?

(**Note:** I'm aware that this is only useful for color-seeing people. I'll deal with color-blindness separately. For the purposes of this question, let's not worry about that.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656179/generate-visually-different-colors-with-an-unknown-color-collection-size/7731511#7731511

Comment: You may get better advice on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/